# [__NSCFNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector / Convert NSCFNumber to a string

Tags: objective-c

FYI: 1st) Not a Obj-C dev. 2nd) all the references I can find about unrecognized selectors are concerning over-releasing, reference issues, ... but this library is not using ARC...

I am returning various AppleScript results via a `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` functions to Mono/C# and all marshaling of in/out parameters, int, arrays, strings, etc.. work fine.

When I get an AppleScript failure from `executeAppleEvent`, the NSDictionary contains multiple entries and I NSLog them and return just the `NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage` to the caller via:

```
strncpy(scriptReturn, ([executionError[@"NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage"] UTF8String]), 254);
```

It all works fine, but if the Applescript failure is concerning a missing function name, the error-based NSDictionary *only* contains one entry (vs. the normal four error key/name pairs):

```
{
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-1708";
}
```

Since I do not have a `NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage` to return, I am trying to return the error number (as a string) and converting it via:

```
strncpy(scriptReturn, ([executionError[@"NSAppleScriptErrorNumber"] UTF8String]), 254);
```

I get an `NSInvalidArgumentException`

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I've various number conversions, NSString assignments, etc.., but always get an "__NSCFNumber" related error.

How do I convert that to a NSString (or ?) so I can `strlcpy` that error number as a string to the out parameter buffer? (And what is a `__NSCFNumber`?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error, the dictionary contain an `NSNumber` object, not an `NSString`.

I would do something like this to be sure (and this makes it easier to read and debug):

```
NSNumber *number = executionError[@"NSAppleScriptErrorNumber"];
NSString *string = [number stringValue];
strcpy(scriptReturn, [string UTF8String]);
```

Comment: Head->Desk, Head->Desk... works fine this way, trying to do it as a one-liner in the `strlcpy` with various conversions has beat me...  Thank you very much!...

Comment: It can be done on one line but I've never understood the desire to make code harder to read and debug by mushing too many nested method calls into one line.

Comment: I agree, and normally would have broken it down into steps, but I just `assumed` there was some magic selector foo that I did not understand and    that was the cause of the error, not something as simple as `NSNumber`... Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to indicate that your question is solved by accepting the answer.